# Azure az login with tenant

Tags: azure

I'm new to Azure stuff so this question may sound silly.

Can I login to sub-accounts in Azure using the CLI 2.0?

What I mean is to have an equivalent of powershell:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId TENANT-GUID -SubscriptionId SUBSCRIPTION-GUID
```

I'm trying to automate creation of apps/service principals on our sub accounts. It appears that using PowerShell I can do it without any specific service principles on the sub accounts but when searching for answers about Azure CLI it's not clear if that is possible.

Thus the question how does one connect through Azure CLI 2.0 to a sub account with --tenant option ?

Answer (score 12):

Try this CLI command:

```
az login --tenant <TenantID>
```

Answer (score 2):

> the question how does one connect through Azure CLI 2.0 to a sub
>   account with --tenant option ?

Sub account, do you mean use Azure AD user account to login Azure via CLI 2.0?

If I understand it correctly, we can use CLI command like this:

```
az login -u jason.ye@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com -p password -t 1fcfxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx8bf8xxxx
```

More information about command `az login`, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_login).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.